# TypeError: Property 'createRole' of object admin is not a function

Tags: mongodb

I am executing following script to create custom role in mongo db . my databse name is admin

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "updaterRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "killop", "inprog" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "createCollection" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "createIndex" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "insert" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find" ] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "update" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

But i am getting following error .

```
TypeError: Property 'createRole' of object admin is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that db.createRole is not a command.

To create a role, you use the command:

`db.runCommand( { createRole: ... } )`

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/